# How can I get get_absolute_url to render a string in views.py in Django

Tags: python, html, django, email, url

I am trying to send an email with HTML content. The email would include a link to a DetailView of a specific instance of a model.

So in the "post" part of view which sends the email, I have something like:

```
html_content = '<a href="'+str(my_model_instance.get_absolute_url())+'">'+str(text)+'</a>'
```

The email that gets sent is:

```
 <a href="<bound method MyModel.get_absolute_url of <MyModel: my instance name>>">my instance name</a>
```

How do I render an HTTP string in views.py?

Thank you

Comment: What does it show without the `str()`

Comment: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'instancemethod' objects

Comment: Can you show the code in `str` too please?

Comment: The error message suggests that you omitted the parenthesis: `my_model_instance.get_absolute_url`.

Answer (score 0):

albar was correct. I had tried get_absolute_url with and without parenthesis but never without parentheses and without the str() function. It did not occur to me to not use the str() function.